# Categorize variable with zero values

Tags: stata

Trying to categorize a variable X which has 82 values as 0, 118 values between 1 and 6, 0 values between 7 and 12, 0 values between 13 and 18, 0 values between 19 and 24.

Tried the following code:

```
gen X = .
replace X = 1 if Y >= 1 & Y <= 6
replace X = 2 if Y >= 7 & Y <= 12
replace X = 3 if Y >= 13 & Y <= 18
replace X = 4 if Y >= 19 & Y <= 24
```

I wish to see X categorized as 0, 1-6, 7-12, 13-18, 19-24. Instead of just 0 and 1.
Current Results:

```
tab X

        X   Freq.   Percent Cum.

        0   82  41.00   41.00
        1   118 59.00   100.00

        Total   200 100.00


* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input int FID byte Y float X
150 0 0
 17 0 0
 95 1 1
  0 0 0
 18 0 0
  1 0 0
 96 0 0
 54 0 0
172 3 1
 97 0 0
 57 1 1
 19 0 0
 98 1 1
151 0 0
 99 1 1
  2 3 1
197 1 1
 55 2 1
 58 1 1
100 0 0
end
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want if I am honest.

Comment: Hi, I wish to categorize X into 5 categories labeled as 0,1,2,3,4. Where, X = 0, if Y = 0, X = 1 if Y lies between 1 and 6, X = 2 if Y lies between 7 and 12, X = 3 if Y lies between 13 and 18, X = 4 if Y lies between 19 and 24. But since none of my Y values exceed 6, the above code shows me X categorized as 0,1 instead of X being categorized as 0,1,2,3,4. Hope it helps.

Comment: When you say if Y lies between 1 and 6 do you mean values or observation number?

Comment: If it is values you mean, your question does not make sense. How do you distinguish between categories 2 and 4 in this case if both are 0?

Comment: No worries. Thank you for your time, I kind of figured out it does not show categories if all the values in those categories are zero.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code does serve for your purpose, i.e. variable `X` is indeed the right set of categories for variable `Y` as you intended.
2. The fact that you only see `X` in the range 0,1 simply means that the data have `no observations` with `Y` falling in other categories. If the data had any `Y` belonging to other categories, then the correct corresponding values of `X` would  show up.
3. A direct way to achieve this output is shown below. Just give it a try.

   ```
   egen YCat = cut(Y), at(0,1,7,13,19,25)
   ```

Comment: Many thanks, Nick Cox sensei, for your perfect edition.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, except crucially that **nothing in your code yields 0 as a result**.

However, I disagree with @Romalpa Akzo on recommending `egen, cut()`. Even an experienced Stata user is unlikely to remember the exact rules used by that function of that command. 
Are lower bounds `>=` or `>`, in particular? What happens above and below the extreme values mentioned? What if you don't want results 1 up?

I prefer explicit code.

Here's another way to do it. With a programmer's understanding that `cond(A, B, C)` yields `B` if `A` is true (non-zero) and `C` if `A` is false (zero), then we can go

```
clear 
set obs 26 
generate Y = _n - 1 

generate X = cond(Y > 24, .,     ///
        cond(Y >= 19, 4,    ///
        cond(Y >= 13, 3,    ///
        cond(Y >= 7, 2,     ///
        cond(Y >= 1, 1, 0   ))))) 

tabulate Y X , missing  


           |                                 X
         Y |         0          1          2          3          4          . |     Total
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------
         0 |         1          0          0          0          0          0 |         1 
         1 |         0          1          0          0          0          0 |         1 
         2 |         0          1          0          0          0          0 |         1 
         3 |         0          1          0          0          0          0 |         1 
         4 |         0          1          0          0          0          0 |         1 
         5 |         0          1          0          0          0          0 |         1 
         6 |         0          1          0          0          0          0 |         1 
         7 |         0          0          1          0          0          0 |         1 
         8 |         0          0          1          0          0          0 |         1 
         9 |         0          0          1          0          0          0 |         1 
        10 |         0          0          1          0          0          0 |         1 
        11 |         0          0          1          0          0          0 |         1 
        12 |         0          0          1          0          0          0 |         1 
        13 |         0          0          0          1          0          0 |         1 
        14 |         0          0          0          1          0          0 |         1 
        15 |         0          0          0          1          0          0 |         1 
        16 |         0          0          0          1          0          0 |         1 
        17 |         0          0          0          1          0          0 |         1 
        18 |         0          0          0          1          0          0 |         1 
        19 |         0          0          0          0          1          0 |         1 
        20 |         0          0          0          0          1          0 |         1 
        21 |         0          0          0          0          1          0 |         1 
        22 |         0          0          0          0          1          0 |         1 
        23 |         0          0          0          0          1          0 |         1 
        24 |         0          0          0          0          1          0 |         1 
        25 |         0          0          0          0          0          1 |         1 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |         1          6          6          6          6          1 |        26
```

Naturally, you could write all the command on one line, but many will find the multiline layout easier to understand and to debug. With nested function calls, each new condition implies a promise to close all the parentheses at the end.

Multiple commands like those in the question are preferred by many Stata users too, so taste is behind many choices.